# Multi-level sub-menu not closing children on click

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, menu

Right now I am working on a multi-level sub-menu based on click instead of hover. I have an issue with closing child sub-menu's when opening another sub-menu. All second-level sub-menu's have to be closed when opening another sub-menu.

This is the project: https://dev.webrandcreative.nl/bespaarbazaar/. Click on the button "Productcategorieën" to show the menu. Click on "Zonnepanelen" and immediately after that on "Verlichting". You'll see that the "Zonnepanelen" sub-menu is not closing.

Here is my code:

```
jQuery('.navigation li.menu-item-has-children > a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!jQuery(this).parent().hasClass('open-submenu')) {
        jQuery(this).parent().parent().find('.open-submenu').removeClass('open-submenu');
        jQuery(this).parent().addClass('open-submenu');
    } else {
        jQuery('.navigation li').removeClass('open-submenu');
        jQuery(this).parent().removeClass('open-submenu').find('.open-submenu').removeClass('open-submenu');
    }
});
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are not closing the already opened sub-menu.

In this line :

```
jQuery(this).parent().parent().find('.open-submenu').removeClass('open-submenu');
```

The parent().parent() only reaches the level of `.menu-item` of that particular `.sub-menu`. And hence does not close any `.open-submenu` from other `.menu-item`s.

So just make sure you close all existing `.open-submenu` before opening a new one.

The following code should work :

```
jQuery('.navigation li.menu-item-has-children > a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!jQuery(this).parent().hasClass('open-submenu')) {
        jQuery('.navigation').find('.open-submenu').removeClass('open-submenu');
        jQuery(this).parent().addClass('open-submenu');
    } else {
        jQuery(this).parent().removeClass('open-submenu').find('.open-submenu').removeClass('open-submenu');
    }
});
```

Comment: This is not working with 3 or more sub-menu levels. Try opening "Zonnepanelen / Montagemateriaal" while using your script.